# Getting Error while sending parameters from child Pipeline to Inner Parent Pipeline in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I referred **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-return-value**

I created one Parent Pipeline ->2 nd Parent Pipeline ->Child Pipeline
I declared one variable inside the  child  Pipeline(Which is return variable).
retval

Then  i validate
@activity("Pname").output.retval
And i am cancelling this child pipeline  using rest API on a particular case
.Then control flow to 2 nd Parent
After that  i tried to get value  from child in 2nd Parent Pipeline
@activity("Pname").output.pipelineReturnValue.retval

But here Im getting error @activity("Pname").output.pipelineReturnValue.retval
cannot be evaluated because  pipelineReturnValue doesnt exits available properties are pipelinename,Pipeline Run Id

Some body help me

Comment: Does the child pipeline succeed after you cancel the pipeline using REST API

Comment: @SaideepArikontham No It is in Cancelled status,Parent 2 got failed

Comment: When are you populating the `retval`? After the API call or before the API call?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Before Cancel Api,After Cancel Api Child Pipeline will get cancelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since the child pipeline is cancelled and the parent pipeline2 fails, you cannot get the return value from child pipeline.
- I have used a set variable to return value and a `fail activity` after that such that pipeline fails (instead of cancelling).

[image]

- When I execute the child pipeline is parent pipeline2, the parent pipeline2 fails.

[image]

- Since the return value is configured before cancelling API call, and cancelling is leading to parent pipeline2 failing, you can give the `on fail` flow to another set variable to get the return value even when the child pipeline fails:

[image]

- Or instead of using the pipeline return value feature, you can write your value to a file so that it can be accessed  anytime as well.

UPDATE:

To store variable output in a csv file use the following steps:

1. Take a sample file with header and just one row and one column (this will be ignored anyway).
   [image]
2. Take this file as source for copy data activity, create an additional column with any name and value as dynamic content (set variable output):

[image]

3. Configure sink as shown below:

[image]

4. Import mapping and delete all the other columns, except for the one created above.

[image]

5. After running the pipeline, it would give the desired results, set variable value in a csv file. You can use lookup any time to retrieve this value:

[image]

Comment: Ok, my set variable value is stored procedure error value.So how I can save the e error to a blob path.Could you please suggest/explain some way

Comment: Hey @BeingReal I have updated the answer to store the set variable output to a csv file. Consider looking into it